# Spring-boot hot reload

Tags: spring-boot, hot-reload

I'm trying to activate hot reload on my spring-boot project with intellij. I have add :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

and

```
-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
```

but i have a problem with activemq, when hot reload start, it give me this error:

```
[ERROR] [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'Consumer.test.VirtualTopic.activemq.ENTITY.T' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2996, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: null
```

I need to stop and start application... does anyone has already facing to the same issue?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enabling hot reload in intellij requires a few more steps. Please refer to the guide here to enable it. Guide - https://www.ladwhocodes.com/java/hot-reload-spring-boot-intellij/621/